# Django - Send JSON with Image to Server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model -

```
class Store(models.Model):
    store_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='store/')
    contactNumber = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, help_text='Contact number')
    start = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    sundayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mondayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tuesdayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    wednesdayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thursdayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    fridayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    saturdayOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have a serializer that can take image field without a couple of fields (which I set myself - the store ID and the owner)

```
 class CreateStoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('name','description','logo','contactNumber',
        'start','end','sundayOpen','mondayOpen','tuesdayOpen','wednesdayOpen',
        'thursdayOpen','fridayOpen','saturdayOpen')
```

I have a view that should handle the request - Image + JSON

```
class StoreDetailView(APIView):
     parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,FormParser, JSONParser)
     permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

     def post(self, request,store_id=None):
        objj = CreateStoreSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(objj.is_valid())
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`objj.errors` gave this message -

```
{
    "name": [ErrorDetail(string="This field is required.", code="required")],
    "logo": [ErrorDetail(string="No file was submitted.", code="required")],
    "start": [ErrorDetail(string="This field is required.", code="required")],
    "end": [ErrorDetail(string="This field is required.", code="required")],
}
```

The serializer validation says its invalid. I tried sending a request from Postman with JSON data except the image field in it. The image field was chosen with form-data with the same name as the imageField (`logo`)
I put the `Content-Type`as `application/json`.

However, serializer validation says false. How do I fix this?

Comment: show what errors are exactly raised by your serializer `objj.errors`.

Comment: @VishalSingh error - `{'name': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'logo': [ErrorDetail(string='No file was submitted.', code='required')], 'start': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'end': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}`

Comment: add this to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems you are sending the `Content-Type` as `application/json`.
- You should send the content type as `multipart/form-data`.
- When you send content type as `application/json` it won't send the files.
- In postman you can do like below to send the data as `multipart/form-data`

[image]

Comment: what about the json body?

Comment: send the json data as a form fields

Comment: what about the code? how do I handle it there? I tried and I think some significant changes need to be done

Comment: it wasnt the same. I had to change it

Comment: it seems you missed something